# Database table doesnt show up in django admin

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and I'm wondering why the database table I created with django models won't show up on the admin page.

Here's what I did in a bash window.
[image]

And my admin page.
[image]

It seems the Cards table has been created but I don't see the table on my admin page and I want to know why. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is in the app's `admin.py` ?

Comment: Also, unrelated, model names should be singular ("Card").

Answer (score 4):

You have to enter your table name in admin.py file like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.site.register(ModelName)
```